# How to resolve "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Server busy, too many connections"

Tags: c#, smtp

Why am I getting this error? And why is all related question does not have a solution?

```
  var emailAdd = mailSettings.EmailAddress;
                            var smtpClient = mailSettings.SMTPClient;
                            password = mailSettings.Password;

                            var Message = new MailMessage(emailAdd, to, subject, "mail body");
                            Message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Report_Card.pdf"));
                            Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            Message.From = new MailAddress(emailAdd, displayName);
                            var smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpClient);
                            var NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
                            NetworkCredentials.UserName = emailAdd;
                            NetworkCredentials.Password = password;

                            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCredentials;
                            smtp.Send(Message);
```

I need a permanent solution to this problem. The mail goes a couple of times and then stop.

Comment: How many messages do you want to send in one batch?

Comment: up to 1000 mails at a go.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually caused by server putting a limit on number of emails that can be transmitted over a SMTP connection. Usually this is done to prevent spamming.

You have choices. **(a)** **Either** you can restrict the number of messages sent at one time so as to not exceed the limit. **(b)** **Or** you can ask your server admin to adjust the limit of server. **(c)** **Or** you may try to reconfigure your connection to the server to automatically disconnect or connect after lets say 5 mails.

It's more of a server problem than a programming problem, although you can try to reconfigure your code to overcome this restriction **(see option C)**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to send many messages over single smtp connection/session (e.g. 50)
2. Be ready to hit limits imposed by server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error while using the Godaddy SMTP,

#1 for me SSL cert was expired (on goDaddy hosted site (e.g. azazaz0101.com) and I was using the same domain to use SMTP (e.g. mail.azazaz0101.com)

#2 didn't received good tech help from hosting provider.

#3 in my view These are genric error to keep everything in your target.
e.g. check
SMTP serevre name, Port, TLS/StartTLS , firewall setting on our Server/PC (port should be open).